# How to inlude geometrical information for image segmentation?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

Is there any interesting work done in image segmentation that combines pixel values and coordinates?

I am trying to detect some objects similar to curved stripes. They are not exactly lined so Hough transform doesn't really help here. After trying different common tools including thresholds (binarisation, OTSU, multi, clustering) and differential filters (Sobel, Prewitt, canny, Laplacian) and watershed the results I have are not good enough.

I have a few ideas in mind. However, I don't mean to reinvent the wheel... this seems to be easy so I suppose some work has been done on it. By any chance do you have good articles about this? Implementations?

Comment: Asking for pointers to external resources is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. You should reword your question to be more specific about the problem you are facing, and showing what you've tried to solve it. Alternatively, look for a different forum to ask this question.

Comment: That said, you should look into Mathematical Morphology to solve your problem. Curved stripes can be filtered using path openings.